# How can I check that a string only contains a defined set of substrings by Excel formula?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, substring

I have a dictionary containing lots of words - I want the user to be able to input a list of substrings, and then a filtered list will be updated, containing **only** words that contain those substrings and nothing else. Any words that contain extra characters the user didn't specify, should not appear. Cell F3 will use a `FILTER` function to create the list. As in the mock-up below:

[image]

What I need is a formula that would generate the `TRUE` or `FALSE` flags from the yellow section (B3:B9), but I'm not sure how to go about this.

I'm sure this could be solved by VBA or Regex using Google Sheets, but I want to know if there's a way to do this by formula, as I don't want this to require a button press or script execution, and my spreadsheet can't be hosted on Google sheets due to its size. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use a combination of LEN/SUBSTITUTE possibly to indirectly count the instance of substrings although this will get quit long and sloppy fast

Comment: And probably wouldn't scale well if there were an increased number of substrings, I imagine. The dictionary contains 180k records, so it would be ideal if the solution didn't do a ridiculous amount of calculations as well.

Comment: I was wondering if your solution could be optimised using a helper column next to Substrings, but I realise now that you would need separate counts of all Substrings for each item in List to filter ... still wouldn't scale well. Shame.

Comment: @urdearboy Especially if the substring contains more than one character - if the substrings are "AD" and "BC", then "ABCD" might generate a false positive (because `Len(Substitute(Substitute("ABCD","BC",""),"AD",""))=0`) unless you check in each combination: (`Len(Substitute(Substitute("ABCD","BC",""),"AD","")) + Len(Substitute(Substitute("ABCD","AD",""),"BC","")) = 2`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use a combination of `ISNUMBER` and `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(MID(A3,ROW(INDEX(A:A,1,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A3),1)),1),$D$3:$D$5,0)))
```

Adjusted formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(MID(A3,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A3))),1),$D$3:$D$5,0)))
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. I've tried it and it works for my purposes perfectly. Would you mind explaining how it works?

Comment: ..`ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))`... Will do. Upvoted, but what would happen with a string of AAB. More a question to OP really. Would that still need to show True?

Comment: Justyna the third parameter of index is optional. You don't need it

Comment: @JvdV whoops! Many thanks, looks much nicer now. Lou, taking ABCD as an example, the formula in the middle `MATCH(MID(A3,{1;2;3;4},1),$D$3:$D$5,0)` is checking - for each character - if it is found in range `D3:D5`. If found, it returns its position, if not found - returns #N/A. In our case, the result of MATCH formula is `{1;2;3;#N/A}`. As there is one #N/A, `SUMPRODUCT` will return an error, which - when evaluated by `ISNUMBER` - will return `FALSE`. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Thank you, that's clear! @JvDv - I would need AAB or ABB or AAAAAAAAB to return true, assuming A and B were in the substring list - the strings can contain any number of characters so long as they only use the substrings on the list. Thanks for the clarification. Justyna's formula evaluates these cases exactly how I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 2):

The test being ran below is subtracting each instance of your dictionary from the length of original string. If the result is `0`, this returns `TRUE`. If not, this returns `FALSE`. This is not case sensitive - `a & A` will be treated equally here.

```
=NOT(LEN(A1)-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),D1,"")))-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),D2,"")))-(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(A1),D3,""))))
```

---

The equation works fine although I don't know if it is an optimal solution for you, but posting as answer in case it is for somebody else. The issue with this approach is the equation gets longer and longer for each character you add to your dictionary. Depending on the size of dictionary and strings to test against, this can get sloppy and calc heavy really quick.

Have you considered a UDF in VBA?

Comment: I will consider a UDF if there is no other way to do it by native formulas. I have no knowledge of VBA which is why I'm keen to find a formula solution first.